# CSS Grid Layout - Masonry style but aligned

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

I need to create a responsive layout for showing a good amount of data, that needs to be accessible in all devices.

I Tried to explain visually where I want to get in this Picture:
[image: My try]

This is my code for the Wrapper and panels.

```
.wrapper {
max-width: 940px;
margin: 0 20px;
display: grid;
grid-gap: 10px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(200px, 1fr));
grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
background-color: #fff;
color: #444;
}

/* fix for unsuported*/
.wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.panel {
background-color: #EBEBEB;
color: #333;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 12px;
flex: 1 1 200px;
margin: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Please add minimal example with HTML and CSS styles. Probably your "fix for unsupported" display property overwrites grid layout and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this markup can help you, but you need to make sure other styles are not overriding your `display: grid`, in your example is very likely that the `display: flex` property you have declared after the grid is messing your styles

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

.grid-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-6 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.grid-9 {
  grid-column: span 2
}

header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
  ;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-1">
    <header>Grid 1</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-2">
    <header>Grid 2</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-3">
    <header>Grid 3</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-4">
    <header>Grid 4</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-5">
    <header>Grid 5</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-6">
    <header>Grid 6</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-7">
    <header>Grid 7</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-8">
    <header>Grid 8</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-9">
    <header>Grid 9</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-10">
    <header>Grid 10</header>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-11">
    <header>Grid 11</header>
  </div>
</div>
```